How to get total list of accounts from V3 coinbase API?
I am using the API GET METHOD for my Coinbase accounts.
I am following this documentation :
https://docs.cdp.coinbase.com/advanced-trade/reference/retailbrokerageapi_getaccounts
Without taking into account here the authorization token, here is the similar code that I am using:
import http.client
import json

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.coinbase.com")
payload = ''
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
conn.request("GET", "/api/v3/brokerage/accounts", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))

This returns me the list of my accounts with their amounts.
I have only type "ACCOUNT_TYPE_CRYPTO" but I don't have some crypto like USDC. I tried to go on each accounts and to get the account considered as active one but It didn't change anything.
Anyone is using this API to get the list of accounts ?
Thanks for your help.
Aurel
I tried to use the path : "/api/v3/brokerage/accounts?limit=250" but It also didn't work.

the only solution is you should get you wallet synchronized on the decentralized manual DApp network so it can safeguard your wallet from being compromised and as well help you restore all DApps data bugs you might be experiencing such high gas fees and swapping error or missing transactions
